# How to automatically add a safeguard for pointer dereferencing?

Tags: c++, pointers

Code crashes when an invalid pointer or smart pointer is dereferenced. An assert is added to help find the problem. For example,

```
Type* p = NULL; // Always initilize to be null.
assert(p); // Add before dereferencing to help to find the problem.
p->f(); // Crashes if p is invalid.
```

My questions is how to add the assert automatically when dereferencing a pointer. For example,

```
#define PTR_RUN(p, f) assert(p); p->f;
```

This works but not well readable and may have some hidden problems from careless uses of macros. Any better ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or may be it's worth using some kind of smart pointers that are throwing exceptions in some cases?

Answer (score 1):

Usually people write,

```
if ( p ) p->f
```

or

```
 p && p->f
```

using short-circuit AND operator

Comment: They are different. If your case, p can be valid or invalid. Both situations have to be handled in the containing function. In my case, p is asserted to be always valid. The assert is used to find code bugs.

Comment: @user1899020 One does not simply detect an invalid non-NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You may overload operator `->` for given type and possibly add assert function in it. I've never done this but it may work.

Comment: Tried but didn't work. To run the function `operator->()`, the pointer must be valid. Thus it crashes before checking the pointer validity in the `operator->()`.